# cursor.execute() insert values from databricks table

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to fill null values of a column in sqldb table which I called to databricks using cursor with values of the same column in datalake table by joining them.

I called a table from sqldb in databricks using cursor(will call it table1)

```
cursor = access_token.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT label_name,unit FROM [dbo].[table1]')
```

| label_name | unit |
| --- | --- |
| A | NULL |
| B | NULL |
| C | NULL |
| D | NULL |
| A | NULL |
| D | NULL |

and I have another table which is from datalake(i will call it table2)

```
df = spark.sql("select distinct label_name,unit from aod.table2 where unit is not null")
```

| label_name | unit |
| --- | --- |
| A | a_1 |
| B | b_1 |
| C | c_1 |
| D | d_1 |

The unit values in table1 are all NULLs
and the required unit values are all available in the table2.

I need to join those table1 and table2 on label_name to fill the NULL values for unit column in table 1 with unit values from table2.

result that I want

| label_name | unit |
| --- | --- |
| A | a_1 |
| B | b_1 |
| C | c_1 |
| D | d_1 |
| A | a_1 |
| D | d_1 |

anyone could suggest any idea to accomplish this?

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sharing information about any SQL libraries you are using is important. Include any relevant import statements in your code so others' can try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the repro from my end, I had created two dataframes name df1 => table1 and df2 = table2 as per your requirement.

[image]

As shown above read both tables into the dataframe and apply inner join as shown below:

```
df = df1.join(df2, df2.label_name == df1.label_name, "inner").select(df2.label_name,df2.unit)
 display(df)
```

[image]

Now you can convert dataframe into a table in the SQLDB as shown:

[image]

You can verify the same from SQL endpoint:

[image]